# SQL query to extract just one field from custom fields table

Tags: sql, tableau-desktop

I have to figure out a custom SQL query within tableau to extract a singular field from a custom fields table. The table is comprised of custom fields for each candidate in a offer process. So every 10 or so rows shows the custom fields (office location, vacation days, salary, etc..) for every candidate.

I want to just extract the custom field labeled "Vacation Days". Here's my table layout:

As shown in picture, the offers table connects to the offer_custom_fields table based on "offer_id"

How do I now extract display_value when the custom_field column = "Vacation Days"?

[image]

Here's kind of my logic, but I don't know SQL at all:

```
SELECT 
    offer_id, display_value
FROM
    offer_custom_fields
WHERE
    custom_field = (WHERE custom_field = ‘Vacation Days’)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh isn't this a field within a column?

Comment: Your query has a table named offer_custom_fields. That table has columns named offer_id, display_value and custom_field (and perhaps more.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause should be like:

```
SELECT 
    offer_id, display_value
FROM
    offer_custom_fields
WHERE
    custom_field = 'Vacation Days';
```

Also possible if you want to be more flexible: (The % stands for zero or more characters)

```
SELECT 
    offer_id, display_value
FROM
    offer_custom_fields
WHERE
    custom_field like '%Vacation Days%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem this should work:

```
SELECT offer_id, display_value FROM offer_custom_fields WHERE custom_field = 'Vacation Days';
```